# Configure a Term Set to be used for this property

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-service, custom-properties

I am creating user profile properties by using powershell, on SP 2013 on prem. 
Some of the properties need to be configured with termsets, and I don't want to have multi value option.

I am struggling to check the checkbox "Configure a Term Set to be used for this property". How can I set that value to true with powershell ?

This is the property I need to set.

[image]